# How confident can we be about the validity of the classification of finite simple groups?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups, simple-groups

The completion of the classification of finite simple proofs was first announced in 1983. However, as late as 2008 minor gaps were still found and closed.

How certain can we be that

1. The proof of the classification theorem is correct
2. Even though there may be mistakes in the proof, at least the result is correct, i. e. our list of finite simple groups is the right one?

Comment: Personally, I feel assuming classification should still be a tentative business until a classification program more amenable to widespread peer review manifests in a [later-generation proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups#Second-generation_classification). Not that I can stand anywhere near the experts in perspective on the group-theoretic details, I just believe in human fallibility's tendency to increase proportional to sheer extent of work and effort, and inversely to the level of open peer review feasible.

Comment: Here are two relevant [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38161) [questions](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/114943).

Comment: I wouldn't bet the farm on it.

Comment: It would not be too surprising to find a gap or a mistake in the thousands of pages that are involved in the classification. But I'm pretty sure most group theorists would agree that if someone discovered a new finite simple group now, it would be extremely shocking!

Comment: I have never seen the detailed proof of the theorem so I should be careful, but I think that the formalization of the proof is important - I mean not only the simple group classification, but also every kind of complicated math theorem. The length of the proof of any theorems are getting more longer as the time flows, and it would be a very hard task for mathematicians to verify every step of the proof. Proof assistant computer programs, such as [COQ](https://coq.inria.fr), would be a great help especially for formal proofs, except the fact that it has a potential flaw of program bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're pretty sure. [This](http://www.ams.org/notices/200407/fea-aschbacher.pdf) is a good read on the status by Aschbacher. At this point, we're trying to simplify the proof because it's pretty messy and not very elegant, not because we aren't sure that it's correct.