# Why was the classification of finite simple groups so hard to prove?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

I have heard that the classification of finite simple groups took many decades and over $10000$ pages. Why was it so hard to prove? Is it because of the sheer number of infinite families and sporadic groups or is it because of something else?

Comment: It was mostly making sure the list (and specifically, the sporadic groups list) was in fact complete, and there weren't any other simple groups hiding around somewhere.

Comment: Actually, yes, because of *many* other things. You can search for some posts with more details, for example [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55343/what-about-the-classification-of-big-finite-simple-groups) and other references. It is definitely not alone bacause of "sheer number of infinite families". There are not many families. The same is true for  simple modular Lie algebras, whose classification is unsolved until today for $p=2$ and $p=3$.

Comment: Even verifying that all groups on the list are simple is not really easy, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498162/verifying-finite-simple-groups). And this is certainly only a very tiny step in the classification proof. The link also refers to R.A. Wilson's book, which is a very good reference for your question.

Comment: Think about how simple the group axioms are. It's incredibly surprising (to me) that we should be able to classify the simple groups _at all_. Why should there be a simple group of size $\approx 8 \times 10^{53}$? Why is there _not_ one of size $\approx 9 \times 10^{53}$? If you like, the classification says that every "large enough" group is not simple (unless it obviously is, because it's a member of one of the infinite families). I have no idea how one would even _begin_ to prove such a result, and unfortuately, it seems like fewer and fewer people are learning how it's done...

Comment: Let $\mathcal{K}$ be the list of groups in the statement CFSG. Then CFSG is the theorem that $G$ is finite simple if and only $G \in \mathcal{K}$. One direction is "easy" (i.e. $G \in \mathcal{K}$ implies $G$ simple) in the sense that most of it is explained in graduate-level textbooks, and could be understood by a motivated student. For some sporadics even the definitions would take some work. The actual main part in CFSG is proving that if $G$ is finite simple, then $G \in \mathcal{K}$.

Comment: The natural approach would be to study the structure of a potential minimal counterexample: simple $G$ which is minimal with respect to $G \not\in \mathcal{K}$. It seems to be very difficult to get a hold of the structure of a such a group $G$, you just don't have that much to work with. One thing you know is that every proper subgroup of $G$ is a "$\mathcal{K}$-group", meaning a group $H$ such that $A \trianglelefteq B \leq H$ with $B/A$ simple implies $B/A \cong S$ for some $S \in \mathcal{K}$. In the proof of the CFSG, they develop a lot of theory on the properties of $\mathcal{K}$-groups.

Comment: See the first volume in the GLS series [link](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/surv-40). Also this article by Aschbacher: [link](https://www.math.unipd.it/~tonolo/didattica/Algebra+2/aschbacher.pdf) at notices of AMS.

Comment: We can talk about technical difficulties behind this problem, but deep down there is no real answer to "why?" questions. Why this is hard but other problems are easier? Or why some problems are harder, still unsolved? It was hard because it was hard. And as such it is a rather philosophical question.