# Why do we trust the Classification of Finite Simple Groups?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups, simple-groups

It seems to me there are a two main reasons to believe a theorem/conjecture to be true:

1. Because it has a correct proof (e.g. the Feit-Thompson Theorem, Dirichlet's Theorem)
2. Because there is an intuitive reason/heuristic for it to be true (e.g. $P \ne NP$, Dirichlet's Theorem)

The former is of course usually the gold standard. However very long proofs may still be regarded as suspicious after a proof has been produced. The longer a proof is, the more likely it is to have undiscovered errors, so that even if no specific gap is known, people don't trust that there isn't a gap. Computer verification of proofs may be used to alleviate these concerns, e.g. the Feit-Thompson theorem was verified with Coq in 2012.

But it seems neither condition convincingly applies to CFSG.

It has a proof, but this proof is tens of thousands of pages spread across hundreds of articles, and the second generation is still going to be thousands of pages long. Moreover, at least one mistake have previously been discovered in the proof: the gap filled by Harada and Solomon in 2008. I am aware CFSG has likely been submitted to significantly more scrutiny than the average proof, but even so, it seems plausible (from my uninformed perspective) that an error could have slipped through. And CFSG has not been computer verified.

There also seems to be no intuitive reason to expect the theorem to be true, as [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/38161) MathOverflow question suggests. Apparently it wasn't known if there were finitely many sporadic groups until late in the proof, suggesting even to those familiar with the proof there is nothing intuitive about it. Though maybe there is something intuitive about it to experts now.

However, the theorem is widely trusted by experts, so I would like to to understand why.

What details I am interested in depends on what the answer is, but **I am not asking about the structure of the proof itself**. My impression is that it is widely believed there may be mistakes in the proof, but any mistake would be fixable. I don't understand how one can be confident that unfixable mistakes don't exist without being confident that no mistakes exist, unless there is an intuitive reason the theorem must be true. So if my impression is correct, an explanation of how you can be confident about one without the other would probably be satisfactory. This might not be anything specific to CFSG.

$$ $$

So my first question is: Am I correct that it is widely believed there may be errors in the proof of CFSG?

If so, how can we be confident those mistakes are fixable? Is there something intuitive about the proof itself that suggests it should be true? (if there is, I accept that I won't be able to understand what the intuitive thing is)

If not, how can we be confident there are no errors without computer verification?

---

This is not a duplicate of [How confident can we be about the validity of the classification of finite simple groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/348539/1107685) as that confirms that we are confident in the result, but doesn't explain where this confidence comes from.

I do not think this question is opinion based, as I am asking why experts trust it, rather than if the person responding trusts it.

Comment: I don't see any reason to think it is "widely believed" that there are errors in the proof. The answer you link certainly suggests otherwise. To "believe" that there is an error is a much more damning assertion than to acknowledge there is a possibility for minor gaps due to how spread apart the proof is across the literature. I don't think confidence in this theorem is different from confidence in other theorems: it comes from knowing that the experts in the fields have spent decades working on it and a trust in the academic peer-review system.

Comment: @Thorgott Am I incorrect in thinking that confidence in the peer-review process sometimes hasn't been enough for experts to completely trust very long proofs? Also, would the presence of minor gaps not also be concerning? how could one be confident, prima facie, that those gaps could be filled?

Comment: The experts *in the relevant field* are the ones that actually read those very long proofs to determine if they're accurate. Everything else here is just speculation. Not every result that has ever been published in a journal was accurate, not every proof ever published in a journal was without errors/gaps even if the result's true. At the end of the day, you either verify a proof of something yourself (and you yourself may, too, make errors)... or you trust. That is the nature of every mathematical result and I don't think this one is fundamentally different, although it is larger.

Comment: Well, there are different levels of errors. Minor things are stuff like (1) typos (2) small mistakes, which are easily corrected using the same ideas. (3) local errors, where some argument in a lemma needs a different idea, but the general strategy of the proof of the theorem works. The literature is full of mistakes like this. Then there are more serious errors, which either make the stated theorem false, or require much more work to fix. I am not sure which type of errors you are talking about.

Comment: Whether a theorem is considered correct or accepted by the mathematical community is also a somewhat social question. Among the experts the general consensus seems to be that the proof of CFSG is fine, so people trust them and are happy to make use of the theorem. In many areas of finite group theory today, you would not get very far in your research without applying CFSG at some point.

Comment: @Thorgott That makes sense to me as a pragmatic argument for mathematicians to accept the CFSG, but it doesn't seem a compelling argument for the truth of the CFSG

Comment: The argument for the truth of the CFSG are the many papers in which the proof is contained. And if you're not devoting many years of your life to becoming a finite group theorist to read those proofs yourself, then you have nothing but the pragmatic question to worry about.

Comment: @ZoeAllen: Now, have meant to ask a totally different question, in view of "but it doesn't seem a compelling argument for the truth of the CFSG"

Comment: I started to believe in the correctness of the result in the early 1980s when John Conway reluctantly agreed that it was likely to be correct, because there was nowhere else where a new sporadic group could conceivably arise. Of course believing in the correctness of the result is not the same as believing that the proof is fundamentally correct. In my opinion, this question is  opinion based!

Comment: So basically the question is: how can we trust others, especially when they make mistakes, or even worse, deliberately lie (yes, such things happen even in maths community)? That's a rather philosophical question. But that is also life: you can't control everything, you will have to trust someone at some point. And I agree, it is a primarily opinion based question.

Comment: And also "how can we be confident there are no errors without computer verification?" How can you be confident that computer verification is correct? You assume those algorithms have no theoretical mistakes? Why, you doubt other proofs. Also you assume that implementations are free of bugs? I'm a software engineer, let me assure you that the number of errors in software is hundreds of times higher than in maths. As I said: you have to trust someone at some point.

Comment: This question seems outside the scope of this site.  It seems more philosophical in nature, about the nature of proof, etc, etc.  Not exactly what this site was meant for.

Comment: You know, many of the big players are still active. Maybe you could contact them and ask. I've found Ron Solomon to be quite friendly by email.